# I can't get JSON objects from a REST API URL

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I have been trying to retrieve JSON files which are basically posts from my database. They can be fetched from the Django REST API that I am running. I can access the url and see the available posts from any devices within my network. However, I can't retrieve them so that they can be posted on my Android app.

My Log in the `postExecute` of my `AsyncTask` doesn't show any JSON objects and is just empty.

It doesn't return any error messages in my logcat so I am not sure what is the problem.

I am trying to make a prototype social networking type stuff where the posts are stored in a database inside my database and fetch them through the API.

I am using `AsyncTask` to connect to my URL and do processing there

Posts.java

```
public class Posts extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

            PostsDetails postDetailsHelper = new PostsDetails();

            postsDoneBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PostsDoneButton);

            postDetailsHelper.callPostDetails("192.168.0.18:8000/api/");

            postDetailsHelper.postDetailsCalled('n');

            postsDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Posts.this, MainActivity.class));

                }
            });
        }

        public class PostsDetails {

            // calls the execute for AsyncTask
            private void callPostDetails(String theurl){
                PostsHelper = new WSAdapter.SendPostsRequest();
                // sets if post details are called
                postDetailsCalled('y');
                // executes AsyncTask
                PostsHelper.execute(theurl);
            }

        }

}
```

WSAdapter.java

```
public class WSAdapter extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    static public class SendPostsRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Add a pre-execute thing
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

            }catch( Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // expecting a response code fro my server upon receiving the POST data
            Log.e("TAG", result);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is Posts.java a subclass of ?

Comment: @MayRestinPeace Oh its actually an activity. I edited it.

Comment: Hey you are calling a static method of an activity from another activity. That is a little unusual. Is there any reason you are making WSAdapter an activity? I think you should make it a normal class.

Comment: @MayRestinPeace I was planning to clean that up later, but my intentions are to make a separate java file for all of my AsyncTasks. I have another AsyncTask within the same file that handles login, which works fine. But I am working on making it a normal class now

Comment: you probably need to add a protocol scheme to your URL (http, https)

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko this actually worked! If you can put your comment as an answer I can mark it. it is now `"http://192.168.0.18:8000/api/"`

Comment: @EllyRichardson that was just a wild guess, but I'm glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the protocol scheme to your URL: `http://`, `https://`, or any other you need.
So it should look like this:

```
postDetailsHelper.callPostDetails("http://192.168.0.18:8000/api/");
```